# Media Resource Support for OData POST in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I would like to create oData controller to upload files

FileDto

1. FileId
2. NameWithExtension (Type: String)
3. Metadata (Type: List)
4. Content (Type: Stream)

=========================Http Request Actions==================

•   GET: ~/Files({id})

```
Content-Type: application/json
Result: FileDto without Content
```

•   GET: ~/Files({id})

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Result: Stream of the File only
```

•   POST: ~/Files

```
Content-Type: ?
Body: FileDto with Content
Result: FileId
```

Not sure how i can achieve this when coupled with OData.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) explains how to create an oDataController.

**1)** To install the package on your project, open the console manager and type this:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Odata
```

**2)** Open your `WebApiConfig.cs` and, inside `Register` method, add this code:

```
 ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<FileDto>("File");            
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: null,
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

**3)** Create your oDataController replacing the `yourDataSourceHere` to use your own class:

```
public class FileController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<FileDto> Get()
    {
        return yourDataSourceHere.Get();
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<FileDto> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        IQueryable<FileDto> result = yourDataSourceHere.Get().Where(p => p.Id == key);
        return SingleResult.Create(result);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post(FileDto File)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        yourDataSourceHere.Add(product);

        return Created(File);
    }
}
```

**OBS:** To test this solution, I changed the `FileDto`'s property `Content`. More specifically, it's type! From `Stream` to `byte[]`. Posted the content as Base64 string.